# Java/Kotlin: Return object from function vs not returning it

Tags: java, object, kotlin, pass-by-reference

Knowing that in Kotlin/Java functions objects are passed as a copy of its reference. I was wondering if `Option 2` is better than `Option 1`. I think in some cases `Option 1` is more readable, but I am not sure if it has any drawback.

**Option 1**

```
fun modifyListFunction(someList: List): List {
    // modifify items in someList
    return someList
}

someList = modifyListFunction(someList)
someList = modifyListFunction2(someList)
someList = modifyListFunction3(someList)
```

**Option 2**

```
fun modifyListFunction(someList: List) {
    // modifify items in someList
}

modifyListFunction(someList)
modifyListFunction2(someList)
modifyListFunction3(someList)
```

Comment: So, it would depend on your intent.  Returning `List` "suggests" that a new `List` will be returned, however, it's also useful in terms of "chaining" function class, for example, `someFunction(someList).add(newItem)` - it's not a big thing, but it can be convenient.  It also means that you wrap the return result into the call of the next function `someList = someFunction(someFunction(someList))`.  In it's purest form, I don't think either is better the other and would require more context before you could answer it one way or another

Comment: It depends on the interface you are aiming for. Do you want a [fluent interface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)? If so, use option 1. Don't spend too much time on these "A vs B" situations unless the decision greatly impacts how you (or your team) will progress. Something tells me choosing Option 1 over Option 2 (or vice versa) will do very little in affecting how your project will progress.. Also, try to avoid foo-bar examples when talking design. I could give deeper insight, but idk what `someFunction`, how important it is, how it may need to scale, etc..

Answer (score 1):

When a function return an object, then the reading programmer will understand that this function is needed to get some object.  If you do something with the object inside the function that returns void, then if you do not read the function, it will not be possible to understand whether this function will affect the object that is passed to it. In addition, the second approach increases the likelihood of errors.
In general, you must adhere to the rule: "If you want to change the input data and do something further with them, the function should return the result. If the input data is used only to read any information from them, then you can not return void"

Comment: I recommend you take a look at what is pass-by-reference in Java and Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Kotlin's Extension Functions. The result would be like **Option 1** but it would be more readable and easier to chain call.

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(Type())
    list.func().func2().func3()
}

class Type

fun List<Type>.func(): List<Type> {
    // modify list
    return this // returns list
}
fun List<Type>.func2() = this
fun List<Type>.func3() = this
```

Comment: Extensions are more used for functions you want to all types of that object. I was looking for more precise functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

In general, programmers reading the signature of option 1 will expect a new list to be returned. So, if you're mutating the list, don't return anything (option 2). If you create a new list, return the new list.

You should use option 1 only if your semantics really makes it obvious that you're returning the same object (e.g. you're building an API that is clearly meant for chaining, like a builder).
But if that were the case, I would probably go for an extension function and make `someList` a receiver instead of an argument.

Note that it's uncommon for collection types to be used this way, though, so you should probably *not* go for option 1 in your case.